# Can someone explain this line of code in Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm very new to Oracle Apex and need help understanding this code I got from a tutorial on creating an app. I've searched and I think it's JavaScript but I'm not even sure.

There is a page and there is a Modal Dialog. This code is supposed to refresh the page that the dialog is attached to once the dialog is closed. In the Dialog section of the Modal Dialog, paste the following line in Attributes:

> `close: function(event, ui) {apex.navigation.dialog.close(true,{dialogPageId:&APP_PAGE_ID.});}`

What is the `close:` part for? I know that `function(..,..)` declares a function in JavaScript.

I also found that apex.navigation.dialog.close(true) closes a dialog, but in this case the tutorial is saying that the user closed the dialog themselves and we're just detecting it so what's the point of this code?

Finally, I know that `&APP_PAGE_ID.` is how you get the ID of a page in Apex but what is `dialogPageId:` written before it for?

[Link to tutorial](https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/dbpm/r/livelabs/run-workshop?p210_wid=942)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/aexjs/apex.navigation.dialog.html). There is even an example of

```
{dialogPageId:3})
```

-- from the docs:

*This example demonstrates closing a modal dialog page, and returning an object of page item, dialogPageId and its value of 3. The returned value can be used by the page that launched the modal dialog, via a Dialog Closed Dynamic Action event, to identify the page ID of the modal dialog that triggered the event.*

About the `close:`. Check the help text for the Dialog > Attributes section in the builder. It says:

[image]

And in the jquery documentation that is mentioned you'll find a "close" event.

So to summarize:
The "close:" is a function that will be fired when the dialog is closed and in the function the dialog id of the closed dialog is set.

Comment: In the tutorial it's Lab 3 > Task 2 > Step 6

Comment: Hi, sorry but I have one more question, I still don't understand how this code refreshes the page?

Comment: I don't think that code refreshes the page, it just sets page item values on close of the dialog. I assume there is a dynamic action on the source page of the that refreshes the region on close of the dialog page.

Comment: Hey sorry just one more question, what does it mean to "Submit Page"? I saw it on a button under Behavior. Just it just mean to refresh a page?

Comment: "Submit Page" is a very basic apex concept. It is NOT a refresh of the page. When you code apex forms, page submit is what you use to save the data through page processing. It is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmdb/how-does-page-processing-and-page-rendering-work.html#GUID-570F6C98-8AEA-433B-A83C-3139C7214E1A) May I suggest you read a couple of basic books on apex or go through some basic tutorials (that movies one is a a pretty complex one) so you get familiar with the basic concepts. There are a lot of tutorials on youtube as well.

Comment: Please post new questions instead of "Sorry but I have one more question" in the comments - this then becomes a conversation between you and me and that is not how Stack Overflow should be used.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any good (really good) YouTube tutorials on Apex? I actually can't find any. A good tutorial in my book is someone who zooms in and out on elements he's talking about in the video.

Comment: Check on apex.oracle.com > scroll to bottom > learn. There are some free courses on oracle.com/oll as well (older versions), check the office hours videos on asktom.oracle.com

Comment: I mean something like the hands-on lab tutorial that I'm using now that allows me to create an app, except that it actually explains what's going on instead of just saying "click here" and "type this". I think that's the only real way to learn anything, not reading 2000 pages of documentation.